# Android: доступ приложения к НОВЫМ логам

Tags: android, логирование, logcat

С помощью:

```
Runtime.GetRuntime ().Exec(...
```

Можно запустить logcat с нужными параметрами и получать строки логов.

Проблема в том, что мне нужны лишь новые логи - те, которые появились с момента старта приложения.

**+ я не могу:**

- Вызвать через Exec: logcat -c, т.к этим я лишу все остальные приложения возможности считать старые логи